# read a disk block as bitmap

Tags: c, bitmap, inode

I am trying to read a block which contains block bitmap and inode bitmap

I read a block as a unsigned char array
than I convert it to binary as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
    for (j = 8; j <=0 ; j--) {
        bits[j] = bitmap[i]%2;
        bitmap[i] = bitmap[i]/2;
    }
    for(t=0; t<8;t++)
        printf("%d\t",bits[t]);
    printf("\n");
    }
```

when I put '0' to char and print it as

```
printf("%d",'0');
```

I get 48
and my bits array contains 00110000
That works, however when I check inode bitmap
it does not work
for example a bitmap is:

1 1 1 0 0 0 0
but I get
0 0 0 0 1 1 1

I could not check if same thing happens with block bitmap.

**To repeat, the code works normal conversation for example it prints 00110000 which is 48, for char '0' which print 48 also. This swapping occurs with inode bitmap.
When I change for it will work for inode bitmap but how can I now it will work for blok bitmap. This will fix the code but the logic is wrong.**

Any idea?

Comment: Your loop is kinda wrong. Maybe 'for (j=7;j>=0;--j)'.

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```
for(t=0; t<8;t++)
        printf("%d\t",bits[t]);
```

print the bit at position 0 (the least significant one) first and the bit at position 7 (the most significant) last.  As you want it to be the other way around, change the loop to:

```
for(t=7; t>=0;t--)
```

or similar.

Comment: I get it is swapped. But my code works for normal conversation. for example it prints 48 for '0' and 0011000 which is also 48. But this is not work for inode bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your bit order is swapped 
big-endian vs little endian.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness
you can swap with `htonl, htons, ntohl, ntohs` family of functions. try `man htons`.
or run your loop in reverse.